# Defining baseURL and EndPoint

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I made a WCF with three methods:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    String devolverPisosA();

    [OperationContract]
    String devolverPisosV();

    [OperationContract]
    String devolverNoticias();
}
```

I need to define **baseAddress** and **EndPoint** in **Web.config** file but I don´t know how:

I´m trying this (and some variations) but this is not working... (between system.serviceModel)

```
<services>
      <service
       name="ProyectoJosephWCF.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/Iservice1/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

    <endpoint address="devolverPisoA"
                 binding="wsHttpBinding"
                 contract="ProyectoJosephWCF.Service1" />
    <endpoint address="devolverPisoV"
                 binding="wsHttpBinding"
                 contract="ProyectoJosephWCF.Service1" />
    <endpoint address="devolverNoticias"
                 binding="wsHttpBinding"
                 contract="ProyectoJosephWCF.Service1" />

  </service>
</services>
```

EDITED: If I´m not defining the baseAddress and endpoint before (using default configuration which was created when I created the project), and I launched the Services1.svc, I can reach the result json through testing windows but I can´t (or at least I don´t know how) to reach that JSON result from Android (by Retrofit). I supposed that I configured Retrofit (baseAddress and Endpoint values wrong), so I decided to set those values by my own...
For that I set the code before in **Web.config**, but I can´t reach them as well...

Beside, I would like to reach JSON result by Mozilla (in browser I mean), because someone said me that could me help to understand what baseAddress and Endpoint I´m using...

EDITED2: Behaviors are settings as:

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

And still don´t reach result by android or browser...

Comment: *Is not working* is a very bad description - what is **not working**? Do you get an error - please post the full and complete error message(s) here! Do you get no response at all? A wrong response? If so: how can you tell it's wrong, what did you expect and what did you get instead??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally... Check it out if you need it.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>


    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

And:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "devolverPisoA")]
        List<pisosAlquiler> devolverPisosA();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `httpGetEnabled="true"` for having WSDL available like below

```
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="NewBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Include the same behavior configuration in your service declaration like

```
      <service name="ProyectoJosephWCF.Service1"
behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior">
```

See [serviceMetadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Edited for your consideration @Rahul

Comment: @EliasMP, setting the behavior is not enough ... you need to bind it with service config. See answer properly.

Comment: Well, I made it, but It doesn´t look different... Which URL is that one who is returning JSON result by browser? @Rahul